# Augment JavaScript Object From External File

Tags: javascript, object, lazy-loading, extend

I have done several searches for this and found many examples for lazy-loading, but I can't find just the right example for what I'm trying to accomplish.  Here's the down and dirty...

I have an object, call it Library:

```
(function() {
    function Library() {
        // some code in here
        this.path = "/library";
    }

    function library() {
        var l = new Library;
        l.lang('en');
        return l;
    }

    Library.prototype.lang = function(lang) {
        lang = lang || 'en';

        var s = document.createElement( "script" );
        s.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        s.setAttribute("src", this.path + "/lang/" + lang + ".js");

        document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[0].appendChild( s );
    }
})();
```

So, what I'm trying to do is lazy-load a "language" file to augment the Library object.  The language file would like something like:

```
(function( Library ) {
    Library.prototype._lang = {
        header: "Welcome",
        greet: "Hello",
        exit: "Goodbye"
    };
} ).bind( this );
```

The problem is (obviously), because of the way it's loaded, the new Library object is returned before it has a chance to be augmented.  I have tried adding an event listener to the document appending the new script tag, but that won't let me "return" the library object.  I'm having trouble finding the right way to defer the return of the library object.

I know about require.js.  It's a great lib, but I don't want to use it for this project.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file using a synchronous [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and `eval`:

```
(function() {

    // ...

    Library.prototype.lang = function(lang) {
        lang = lang || 'en';
        load(this.path + "/lang/" + lang + ".js");
    };

    function load(url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url, false);
        xhr.send();
        if (xhr.status !== 200) {
            console.log("Failed to load " + url + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        } else {
            eval(xhr.responseText)(Library);
        }
    }
})();
```